# EMGU CV in C# Displaying item properties from a list into a list box

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, hough-transform

I have implemented detection using HoughCircles on to a still image, The method automatically detects the radius of circles to enable drawing them. Currently I am only able to display the radius of circles one by one by into a text box each as follows:

txtDetect.Text = circles[0].Radius.ToString();

txtDetect1.Text = circles[1].Radius.ToString();

and when I try to convert it to a list it gives the following error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Emgu.CV.Structure.CircleF[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

The related code is as follows:

```
        #region circle detection
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        double cannyThreshold = 100.0;
        double circleAccumulatorThreshold = 80;
        CircleF[] circles = CvInvoke.HoughCircles(uimage, HoughType.Gradient, 2.0, 20.0, cannyThreshold, circleAccumulatorThreshold, 5);

        watch.Stop();
        msgBuilder.Append(String.Format("Hough circles - {0} ms; ", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        #endregion

        imgOriginal.Image = img;
        this.Text = msgBuilder.ToString();

        #region draw circles
        Image<Bgr, Byte> circleImage = img.CopyBlank();

        foreach (CircleF circle in circles)
        {
            circleImage.Draw(circle, new Bgr(Color.Brown), 2);
        }
        imgDetect.Image = circleImage;
```

Thank you kindly for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a very simple solution:

```
        lstRadius.Items.Clear();
        foreach (CircleF circle in circles)
        {
            circleImage.Draw(circle, new Bgr(Color.Brown), 2);
            lstRadius.Items.Add(circle.Radius.ToString());
        }
```